# Decoding IoT protobuf message from gcp PUB/SUB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, iot, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a IoT device sending data through google PUB/SUB in protobuf format. When I decode data from PUB/SUB message with https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ it looks correct, it corresponds to my  object definitions. This is an example of a data that I get in the PUB/SUB ( CAEQneDs_gQaIAjK4Oz-BBIVEKA4GOzMmQEgzLPUAyjIEzD8y_4NGKBWIg0QvvACGgAogPwCMNogKgkQCRgBKOKFqR4= ).

The first issue that I have is why is it not encoded in Base64 format, shouldn't GCP encode it?
Another thing is when I try to decode the data I get this exception:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException$InvalidWireTypeException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.

    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:134)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:527)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:491)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:604)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:304)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readGroup(CodedInputStream.java:837)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:518)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageV3.java:320)
    at com.agurotech.node.common.Mqtt$MqttWeatherPayload.<init>(Mqtt.java:1626)
    at com.agurotech.node.common.Mqtt$MqttWeatherPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(Mqtt.java:2849)
    at com.agurotech.node.common.Mqtt$MqttWeatherPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(Mqtt.java:2843)
    at com.agurotech.node.common.Mqtt$MqttWeatherPayload$Builder.mergeFrom(Mqtt.java:2206)
    at com.agurotech.node.common.Mqtt$MqttWeatherPayload$Builder.mergeFrom(Mqtt.java:1997)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:420)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:317)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:222)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:542)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:317)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:214)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:536)
    at com.agurotech.lora.processing.util.IotWeatherMessageDecoder.parseWeatherPayload(IotWeatherMessageDecoder.kt:12)
    at com.agurotech.lora.processing.handlers.DecoderHandlerTest.decode iotcore weather payload(DecoderHandlerTest.kt:220)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

These are my protobuf message definitions:

```
message MqttPayload {
  bool installation = 1;         /// True if data has been taken during installation
  uint64 deploymentTime = 2;     /// Gps timestamp (seconds) of deployment
  repeated SensorData data = 3;
  PhysicalStatus status = 4;
  Version firmwareVersion = 5; /// Firmware version
}
message WeatherSensorData
{
    sint32 result = 1;             /// 0 or error code
    sint32 period = 2;             /// The period over which values were calculated in seconds. Integer
    sint32 temperature = 3;        /// Temperature as q7_16. -128 signifies an error
    sint32 humidity = 4;           /// Humidity as q7_16. -128 signifies an error
    sint32 windspeed = 5;          /// Windspeed as q7_16. -128 signifies an error
    sint32 winddirection = 6;      /// Winddirection as q7_16, in degrees, 0 indicating North
    sint32 rain = 7;               /// Amount of rain that has fallen in mm over period of time. Integer
}

message WeatherData
{
    uint64   gpsTime = 1;
    WeatherSensorData weather = 2;
    sint32   boardTemperature = 3;
    sint32   boardTemperatureResult = 4; /// 0 or error code
}
message Version {
  uint32 maj              = 1;       /// Major version
  uint32 min              = 2;       /// Minor version
  uint32 build            = 3;       /// Revision
  
  /// The following field should not be part of an official release
  uint32 commit           = 4;       /// Number of commit since release
  uint64 sha1             = 5;       /// Short commit up to 8bytes (16 digits)
  bool   dirty            = 6;       /// "dirty" state
}
message PhysicalStatus
{
  sint32     temperature     = 1;        /// Temperature as q7_8
  sint32     inclination     = 2;        /// Inclination as q7_8
  GPSPos     gpsPos          = 3;        /// GPS position
  GPSStatus  gpsStatus       = 4;        /// GPS status
  sint32     battery         = 5;        /// Battery status in % as q7_8
  sint32     batteryVoltage  = 6;        /// Battery voltage in V as q7_8
  sint32     batteryCurrent  = 7;        /// Battery current in A as q7_8
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and you include no code (How are you devices marshaling and shipping messages? How are you unmarhsaling the pub/sub messages?) to explain why you get the error. The string that you include **is** base64 encoded. When it is decoded, it will be a `[]byte` and need to be unmarshaled by your proto-generated code in order to convert it into e.g. Java classes.

Comment: As @Duje mentioned already without any [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) its really hard to tell what might be causing the issue. I have also noticed that in proto `message PhysicalStatus` you have `GPSPos` and `GPSStatus` but you did not provide any definition for that

Comment: If the payload works using the online protocol buffer decoder, then I would assume your problem is in the code you're using to read the byte-array encoded payload using the protocol buffer package. Please provide a code snippet.